# ansible-vault-inline plugin not working in vscode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ansible, ansible-vault

I just installed ansible-vault-inline plugin in vscode but it's not working as exxpected and giving following error when I press 'ctrl+alt+0'

```
A system error occurred (spawnSync C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT)
```

Here are my plugin settings:

```
ansible-vault vault ID for encryption: test1
Full path of ansible-vault executable: /mnt/c/Users/Public/vscode-ansible-vault
ansible-vault password file path or vault-identity-list: /mnt/c/Users/Public/pass.txt
ansible-vault password text: test123
```

I have installed vscode on windows 10 and installed ubuntu from MS Store and installed ansible on top of that.

Comment: Can someone pls suggest?